# Lua: узнать текущую ОС

Tags: lua

Необходимо из луа узнать тек. ОС (для задания пути работы). Как это сделать?

Comment: использовать `os.capture 'uname' ` для linux/mac: если ошибка, то windows. На [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295052/how-can-i-determine-the-os-of-the-system-from-within-a-lua-script) есть несколько советов

Comment: @approximatenumber, os.capture надо определить (на SO есть как)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

способы определения платформы изложены, например, в [документации](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PlatformDetection).

пример с использованием библиотеки [apr](http://peterodding.com/code/lua/apr/), в частности, функции [apr.platform_get()](http://peterodding.com/code/lua/apr/docs/#apr.platform_get), которая может возвратить одну из строк — `UNIX`, `WIN32`, `NETWARE` или `OS2`:

```
apr = require ("apr")
print (apr.platform_get())
```